# PHP SphinxClient not returning results as expected

Tags: php, sphinx

I am trying to use `SphinxClient` for PHP to search for text based locations in a GeoDatabase. Here's the code that I use:

```
$SphinxClient=new Sphinx\SphinxClient();
$SphinxClient->setServer('myserver', 'myport');
$SphinxClient->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$result=$SphinxClient->query('@country DE', 'geonames');
$result2=$SphinxClient->query('@country US', 'geonames');
```

If I run the above code, `$result` finds no matches, and reports no errors or warnings, `$result2` finds a bunch of matches, and also reports no errors.

If I run the following two queries from command line (which should be the equivalent for the above two php client queries), they both return results:

```
select geonameid_attr from geonames where match('@(country) "DE"');
select geonameid_attr from geonames where match('@(country) "US"');
```

Here's also the relevant part from the sphinx.conf file, from which I built the sphinx table:

```
sql_query = SELECT geonames.geonameid, geonames.geonameid AS geonameid_attr, geonames.name AS name, geonames.asciiname AS asciiname, geonames.alternatenames AS alternatenames, geonames.country AS country, geonames.fcode AS fcode FROM geonames WHERE fcode IN ('PPL', 'PPLA', 'PPLA2', 'PPLA3', 'PPLA4', 'PPLC', 'PPLCH', 'PPLF', 'PPLG', 'PPLH', 'PPLL', 'PPLQ', 'PPLR', 'PPLS', 'PPLW', 'PPLX', 'STLMT') OR fcode LIKE 'ADM%'

sql_attr_uint = geonameid_attr
```

What could be the problem? Am I rusing the `SphinxClient::query` function incorrectly?

Comment: do you have country defined as a attribute?  Likely you'll want it as a fulltext index though, for performance reasons.

Comment: I am rather new to Sphinx, but the only defined attribute I have if I understand it correctly, is `sql_attr_uint = geonameid_attr` . If I understand correclty from the documentation, I can only define attributes from int, float, or boolean values. How should I define the country attribute? Would it solve the above mentioned problem?

Comment: This is what I would use for it, http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-field-string .  And yes likely it would as sphinx cant search on what it doesn't know about, you tell it what is filterable with the attributes, but searching is only done on the fulltext indexes

Comment: Okay, I've added it, and it now also returns the country alongside the unique id, but the PHPClient version still doesn't work:|

Comment: Basically, what I can't figure out, is how to query by a single field with the SphinxPHPClient

Comment: The code looks fine (and you need the country as a field to use in text quest) - frankly I suspect its something else wrong. How you are looking at the results.

Comment: Also dont need geonameid_attr at all. Its just duplicating the id into an attribute. You can use the 'id' everywhere you can use the attribute.

Comment: If I try with only an id, when I am using `indexer` it gives an error, and I can't search at all:|